# How indexing on a date field that is constantly updated or omitted affect performance?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

In mongo, I have a collection with a date field called last_updated I would like to index. Reason being, I am often querying a range and sorting on that date field. I feel I can optimize via indexing this field. I would like to add as a side note: this collection does see a lot of writes and updates.

I would like to know the implications. It's to my understanding that updates are heaviest transaction in a b-tree index structure. My concern is that indexing on a field that is updated often would affect performance. Would you mind explaining whether it would or wouldn't and if not why it would be just as normal as indexing on another date field (one that is not updated).

Comment: As with any index, adding the index is going to slow down your updates as the index will need to be updated along with the document.

Comment: but if the indexed field is constantly updated, does it affect the performance more than a field that is not updated in addition to the field potentially being omitted. also if you can explain what exactly is happening if it does, i would appreciate it